# Не получается запустить файл .py из командной строки

Tags: python, path, командная-строка

Добавил в `PATH` новый путь : `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PythonExperiment\` , где `PythonExperiment` - папка, в которой лежит искомый файл `script1.py`.

При вводе в командной строке :

```
python  script1.py
```

Выдает следующую ошибку:

> ```
> python: can't open file 'script1.py': [Erno 2] No such file or directory
> ```

При этом, когда ввожу следующее :

```
python C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PythonExperiment\script1.py
```

все работает на ура. Как это исправить?

Comment: Создайте ярлык и им запускайте. Тот трюк с PATH сработал если бы в консоли просто выполняли `script1.py`, тогда бы он нашелся. А когда вы написали `python script1.py`, то питон искал файл `script1.py` в своей текущей активной директории. Абсолютный путь `python C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PythonExperiment\script1.py` всегда будет работать, т.к. поиск будет идти не по относительному пути (`python script1.py`)

Comment: Если я ввожу просто script1.py, в консоли просто появляется новая строка для ввода, но ничего не происходит, хотя файл содержит в себе инструкцию print, которая точно должна выполняться.

Comment: Про `script1.py` я привел пример чтобы вы поняли почему затея с PATH не работает, а так, для запуска `.py` нужен питон. Попробуйте создать ярлык к файлу `.py` и в свойствах ярлыка в поле Target в начало добавить `python`. После этого при запуске ярлыка выполнится тот `python C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PythonExperiment\script1.py`

Comment: В папках из ``PATH`` ищутся программы и консольные команды. А ``script1.py`` в данном случае ни то и ни другое, это аргумент.